# How do I know if I'm getting an actual EXIT CODE from GetExitCodeProcess?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, exit-code

I am making a program that checks an existing process and returns its exit code... **IF** it's an exit code. If the program errored out, it returns a -1.

My code right now looks like:

```
HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess( SYNCHRONIZE | PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, FALSE, pid );
if(!hProcess) {
    switch (GetLastError()) {
       //Handle errors and such
    }
} else {
    WaitForSingleObject(hProcess, INFINITE);
    int exit_code;
    GetExitCodeProcess(hProcess, &exit_code);
    return exit_code;
}
```

But, as the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getexitcodeprocess) says, GetExitCodeProcess can return the exit code OR THE EXCEPTION VALUE. I don't want the exception value! If the process errors out I want to return -1!

Is there any way to tell the difference? Is there an easy way to tell that the process crashed?

Comment: Unlike Unix, Windows doesn't reserve part of the 32-bit status code to store the reason for an abnormal termination. We may assume that an application won't intentionally exit with a system `NTSTATUS` error code (0xC0000000-0xCFFFFFFF), but it could, or it could be externally terminated via `TerminateProcess` with such a code even thought it's not due to a crash (unhandled exception). We can't know because `TerminateProcess` is always how a process ultimately terminates, even via `ExitProcess`.

Comment: You could also add the process to a job object (**if it's not already in a job**), add a completion port to the job, and check if the completion port receives a `JOB_OBJECT_MSG_ABNORMAL_EXIT_PROCESS` in which case it indicates the process has crashed (see the [`JOBOBJECT_ASSOCIATE_COMPLETION_PORT structure`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-_jobobject_associate_completion_port) for more information).

Comment: @Neitsa, the Job object message is for a possible abnormal exit such as `STATUS_STACK_OVERFLOW` or `STATUS_CONTROL_C_EXIT`. Nothing stops a process from using `ExitProcess(STATUS_CONTROL_C_EXIT)` (in fact it's what the console `CtrlRoutine` does), but at least with your suggestion (i.e. `JOB_OBJECT_MSG_ABNORMAL_EXIT_PROCESS`), *categorizing* abnormal exit codes is left up to the system.

Comment: On a side note, you can't use an `int` for the `exit_code` because `GetExitCodeProcess()` expects a `DWORD` (`unsigned long`) instead.

Comment: To me, if a user terminates as an `NSTATUS` error code, they want it to be treated like an error. So unhandled exception values are usually 0xC0000000-0xCFFFFFFF? Is there documentation for that?

Comment: NT uses `NTSTATUS` codes within the kernel, for system-call results, and the runtime library and loader in ntdll.dll. Normally these status codes do not leak to the Windows API. They get mapped to 16-bit Windows error codes via `RtlNtStatusToDosError`. If we see them, it's almost always as exception codes, which will be system error codes. The upper 4-bit nibble is thus 0xC (`STATUS_SEVERITY_ERROR`, with the [C]ustomer and N bits as 0). There's a well-known set of status codes for unhandled exceptions defined in winnt.h, and corresponding `EXCEPTION_*` macros are defined in minwinbase.h.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can tell from outside the process unless you debug it.

Ignoring threads, conceptually you can think of it something like this:

```
MainThread(EXE*exe)
{
  __try
  {
    NTDLL_LoadDlls(exe);
    int retval = exe->WinMain();
    ExitThread(retval); // Exits the process if there is only one thread
  }
  __catch(...)
  {
    int exceptcode = getexceptioncode();
    WER_ReportCrash(exe, exceptcode);
    TerminateProcess(GetCurrentProcess(), exceptcode);
  }
}
```

0 usually means success and 1 means generic failure, anything else is probably a problem. Low codes (<=255) could have meaning but they are program specific. >= 0xC0000000 is probably a crash.

Comment: A crucial point is that `ExitThread`, if it's the last thread, will call `TerminateProcess(GetCurrentProcess(), retval)`. To the kernel, there is no difference here compared to the abnormal exit that calls `TerminateProcess(GetCurrentProcess(), exceptcode)`. `ExitProcess` is similar, except it uses two `TerminateProcess` calls, the first of which terminates all other threads.

Comment: @eryksun I think ExitThread calls ExitProcess, not TerminateProcess?

Comment: I meant only that ultimately, if it's the last thread in the process, `ExitThread` (i.e. `RtlExitUserThread`) will call `TerminateProcess` (well, `NtTerminateProcess`) -- the key point being that it's ultimately indistinguishable from the `TerminateProcess` call due to an unhandled exception. But yes, it does so via `ExitProcess` (i.e. `RtlExitUserProcess`) in order to cleanly shut the process down (via `LdrShutdownProcess`). In this case, the fact that `ExitProcess` terminates all other threads is a non-issue, since it's the last thread anyway.